# Exclude duplicated checkouts -- SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Running SQL Server 2012

I have a query that counts the number customers who have checked out a book. It also counts those who have checked out the same book twice. All of this is added into a column `Customers Checked Out.` The problem is that I do not want it to count those who have already checked the book out more than once.

So for instance,

```
Book Title                  Customers Checked OUt 
Title of Book1                         2
Title of Book2                         3
TItle of Book3                         1
```

In this case Title of book 1 was actually only checked out one but checked out twice. How can I only get it to say 1 time and not 2

ADDING QUERY

```
SELECT 
    Book.title AS 'Title of Book', 
    COUNT(Book_Rental.Book_id) AS 'Customers Checked Out'
FROM Book
JOIN Book_Rental ON Book.Book_id = Book_Rental.Book_id
JOIN Customer ON Book_Rental.Customer_id = Customer.customer_id
GROUP BY Book.Title
ORDER BY [# of Customers Rented] DESC;
```

Comment: what's your current query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, your query is something like:

```
select BookTitle, count(*)
from CheckOuts
group by BookTitle
```

You want to change the `count()` to a `count(distinct)`:

```
select BookTitle, count(distinct customerId)
from CheckOuts
group by BookTitle
```

Since you provided the query, I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT Book.title AS 'Title of Book', 
       COUNT(distinct Book_Rental.Customer_id) AS 'Customers Checked Out'
FROM Book
JOIN Book_Rental ON Book.Book_id = Book_Rental.Book_id
JOIN Customer ON Book_Rental.Customer_id = Customer.customer_id
GROUP BY Book.Title
ORDER BY [# of Customers Rented] DESC;
```

Comment: This sets all the values for Customers Checked Out to `1`.  In the table Book_Rental, there are multiple customers who have rented the same book, therefore for say `Title of Book2` should have a result of `2`

Comment: Your last edit did the trick! where can DISTINCT Be used? only in the select statements?